# error al cargar la pagina en una app vue ya publicada

Tags: nodejs, vue.js

Tengo una App Vue que utiliza vue-router, para poder publicarlo utilice lo siguiente:

1. instale express
2. cree un archivo server.js
3. inserte el siguiente codigo

**CODIGO**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('server started '+ port);
```

4. node server.js

Con eso ya se ha publicado, pero cuando presiono f5 o recargo la pagina ya no puede encontrar la ruta o directorio en el navegador, perdonen mi ignorancia pero necesito ayuda :(

Comment: Pregunta, porque hiciste todo eso si el cli de vue lo hace todo solo y te deja ya un esqueleto de un programa vue funcionando?

Comment: @gbianchi porque el vue-cli te deja la versión dev funcionando, pero si quieres servir la versión estática necesitas un webserver que levante sólo la carpeta estática.No tiene sentido tener webpack hot reloader escuchando en producción por los siglos de los siglos. Por lo que nos dices la primera vez carga y al refrescar ya no carga? ¿Cambia la url? ¿Estás usando vue-router?

Comment: pero si compilas nmp run built, es la version de produccion. tal vez no estoy entendiendo algo de tu pregunta...